# 文字列を漢字かそれ以外でグルーピングする

Tags: java, 正規表現, unicode

Javaで文字列を与えて「漢字かそれ以外か」でグルーピングしたいです．つまり、1文字とも取りこぼす文字はあってはならないのが条件です．次のようなサンプルを作ってみたのですが...

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {

    private static Pattern cjkIdeoGraphicOrNotPattern = Pattern.compile("(?U)([\\P{InCJKUnifiedIdeographs}]&&[\\P{InCJKUnifiedIdeographsExtensionA}]&&[\\P{InCJKUnifiedIdeographsExtensionB}]&&[\\P{InCJKUnifiedIdeographsExtensionC}]&&[\\P{InCJKUnifiedIdeographsExtensionD}])+|([\\p{InCJKUnifiedIdeographs}]|[\\p{InCJKUnifiedIdeographsExtensionA}]|[\\p{InCJKUnifiedIdeographsExtensionB}]|[\\p{InCJKUnifiedIdeographsExtensionC}]|[\\p{InCJKUnifiedIdeographsExtensionD}])+");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String target = "2000年问题 2001年问题";
        Matcher matcher = cjkIdeoGraphicOrNotPattern.matcher(target);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Matches = \"" + matcher.group() + "\"");
        }
    }
}
```

結果は漢字の部分だけにマッチしてしまいます．

```
Matches = "年问题"
Matches = "年问题"
```

望まれる結果は

```
Matches = "2000"
Matches = "年问题"
Matches = " 2001"
Matches = "年问题"
```

なのですが、このようなことって正規表現で実現できますでしょうか？

以上 よろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: 何を漢字と見なすかは人それぞれです。特に挙げられている例では中国語も含まれているようですし。質問者さん自身でUnicode文字一覧を見てどの範囲かを決定する必要があると思います。その上で改めて「これこれこういう範囲」を正規表現で表現できるか？という質問をされた方がいいかと。

Comment: 範囲の点、説明が足りずすみません．今回の場合は質問の例のコード中の正規表現で書きましたが、漢字の範囲はCJK Unified Ideographs, CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A～Dにてと考えております．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

問題は、文字クラスの積の書き方の間違いです。`&&[` は `[ ]` の内側に書く必要があります。

```
  "(?U)([\\P{...}&&[\\P{...}]&&[\\P{...}]&&[\\P{...}]&&[\\P{...}]]+..."
```

この場合は文字クラス積を使わなくてもいいかと思います。否定 `^` で十分です。

```
private static String cjkIdeoGraphic =
    "\\p{In...}\\p{In...A}\\p{In...B}\\p{In...C}\\p{In...D}";
private static Pattern cjkIdeoGraphicOrNotPattern = Pattern.compile(
    "(?U)([^" + cjkIdeoGraphic + "]+|[" + cjkIdeoGraphic + "]+)");
```

Comment: バッチリ動きました (^^♪